# I want to install Norton Family. Will it require me to reboot?

Tags: windows, reboot, norton-family

I want to install the free version of [Norton Family](//onlinefamily.norton.com/), a parental-control software package.  But I have some other software running which I don't want closed and restarted.  When I install Norton Family, will I be required to reboot before it will work?

Comment: So install it after you install some updates and before a normal reboot

Comment: @Ramhound: Your idea is a good one, but I want to install Norton Family sooner than that. By the way, someone downvoted my question and answer; why might this have been?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Norton Family 3.2.1.28 on a VM running Windows 10 Insider Preview in order to find out.

It didn't ask me to reboot, and it works fine despite the fact that I haven't rebooted.

(Side note:  later, after I ran its uninstallation procedure, it *did* ask me to reboot.)